# Prove $A \cap B = A − (A − B)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$A$ and $B$ are sets, how would I prove the following equality:

$A∩B = A-(A-B)$

Would I be correct in saying that if I take $x$ to be in $A-(A-B)$, it means that $x$ is in $A$, but not in $A-B$. Now, suppose temporarily that $x$ was not in $A∩B$, however, we already know that $x$ is in $A$, so that means $x$ cannot be in $B$. But then, since $x$ is in $A$, but not in $B$, $x$ must be in $A-B$, which contradicts what I just discovered. Therefore, $x$ must be in $A∩B$.

Suppose $x$ is in $A∩B$, then $x$ is in both $A$ and $B$. I know from this that $x$ cannot be a part of $A-B$ because that would imply that $x$ is part of $A$, but not part of $B$. Since $x$ is already part of $A$, but not part of $A-B$, it follows by definition that $x$ is in $A-(A-B)$.

Would I be correct in saying this? I can write these proofs out in words but my notation is poor, how would I write this in strict set notation?

Comment: Directly: $$\;x\in A-(A-B)\implies x\in A\;\wedge\; x\notin A-B\implies x\in A\;\wedge\;x\in B\implies x\in A\cap B$$

Comment: KCarr, your arguments hold. @DonAntonio summed it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done pretty mindlessly using De Morgan's laws:

$$A - (A - B) = A \cap (A - B)^c$$
$$= A \cap (A \cap B^c)^c$$
$$= A \cap (A^c \cup B)$$
$$= (A \cap A^c) \cup (A \cap B)$$
$$= A \cap B$$

Answer (score 3):

You have the idea right.
One can argue very formally as follows
$$\begin{eqnarray} &x\in A-(A-B)\\\iff &x\in A\land x\notin(A-B)\\\iff& x\in A\land\neg(x\in A\land x\notin B)\\\iff& x\in A\land(x\notin A\lor x\in B)\\
\iff& (x\in A\land x\notin A)\lor (x\in A \land x\in B)\\
\iff& \bot\lor (x\in A \land x\in B)\\
\iff& x\in A \land x\in B\\
\iff& x\in A\cap B\\
\end{eqnarray}$$
Thus reducing everything to predicate calculus.

Actually, unless this level of formaility is specifically required (e.g. during an introductory course) I prefer a wordy proof - somewhere between what you wrote and what I wrote above (and in fact vrey close to what you wrote): neither a long novel, nor a mere pile of symbols.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you are right.
I think this is enough for the proof